# Pb with responsive image sizes in WP 4.4

Tags: responsive, images

I don't understand how to customize responsive sizes images in WP 4.4.1. 
The only available hooks that I see are `wp_calculate_image_srcset` and `wp_calculate_image_sizes`, and neither has the named image size that was asked for as a parameter. So that would mean that you can correct image sizes, but with no knowledge of the context?

One simple case, with one banner and 3 image sizes :

- Mobile (780x200)
- Tablet (980x250)
- "Desktop" (1600x300).

What I want is to be able to tell WP core that I want those dimensions at width w1, w2 and w3 (which would be here 0-780, 781-980 and 981+), or that I want the named image size mobile for w1, tablet for w2 and desktop for w3.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I handle the context like this:

```
function wpse_216001_srcset() {
    // generate your Srcset here and return 
}
function wpse_216001_sizes() {
    // generate your sizes attribute here and return
}

add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'wpse_216001_sizes', 10 , 2 );
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'wpse_216001_srcset', 10 , 5);

// call one of the standard WP image output functions here

remove_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'wpse_216001_sizes', 10 );
remove_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'wpse_216001_srcset', 10 );
```

You can either do this in your template or make a wrapper function in your functions.php and then call this as a template tag.

Comment: please never use function with `my_` here. Use a prefixe like wpse_question number_. In this case making `my_srcset` into `wpse_216000_srcset`